# Dealing a single card to an ArrayList of Players

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

i am trying to build a blackjack card game using an ArrayList. I am having trouble figuring out the logic for dealing a single card to all players-- i think my question has to do more with using iterators....

the issue is in the //deal cards section of GameRunner. i know I'm not using the itr correctly to assign a new card to each player in the ArrayList.

```
import java.util.*;

public class GameRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numDecks = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);;
    int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    String pName;

    //init
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Deck gameDeck = new Deck(numDecks, true);
    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

    players.add(new Player("Dealer"));

    //create players
    do{
        System.out.print("Enter an name of a player:  ");
        pName = sc.next();
        players.add(new Player(pName));
        numPlayers--;
    }while( numPlayers > 0);

    System.out.println(players.toString());


    //deal cards
    ListIterator<Player> itr = (ListIterator<Player>) players.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()){
      itr.drawCard(gameDeck.dealNextCard());
    }

  }//end main

}//end GameRunner class

...
```

from the Player Class:

```
    public boolean drawCard(Card aCard){

    //print error if player is already at the card max
    if(this.numCards == MAX_CARDS){
        System.err.printf("%s's hand already has " + MAX_CARDS + 
                "cannot add another card\n", this.name);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    //add new card in the next slot and increment the number of cards
    this.hand[this.numCards] = aCard;
    this.numCards++;

    return (this.getHandSum() <= 21);
}
```

from the Deck class

```
    public Card dealNextCard(){ 
    if (numCards == 0){
        System.err.print("Too Few Cards to Deal another card");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    this.numCards--;
    return mCards.pop(); 
}
```

Comment: You're missing [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#next()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the section that uses the iterator, use the following:

```
// deal cards
for (Player p : players) {
  p.drawCard(gameDeck.dealNextCard());
}
```

This `for (Player p : players)` is called an **enhanced for loop**, sometimes also referred to as a **for-each loop**. It loops through each item in an `Iterable` object. An `Iterable` object is an object that implements the `Iterable` interface.

`players`, which is of type `ArrayList<Player>`, implements the `Iterable<Player>` interface, so it can be used in an enhanced for loop.

The enhanced for loop I used above is equivalent to the following:

```
Iterator<Player> iter = players.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  Player p = iter.next(); // this statement is what your code was missing
  p.drawCard(gameDeck.dealNextCard());
}
```

Here is a link to an Oracle tutorial on enhanced for loops: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Hope this helps!